# Fail reading files from cyberduck when publishing website

Tags: c#, html, rider, cyberduck

I have got domain name, got webhotel. The next i am trying to do is publishing my website, that i have build in Rider IDE, .net core. When i am doing this, the only thing that show on my the website(internet) is the files from my Rider program.

MARK: The Rider file is just an test program for lower upload time.

First i make an "custom publish server" in Rider, right click my project. Then click "publish" and fill the form.

The details behind "Remote server" where i set up the SFTP linked to my web hotell, host, username, password. This is fine and connection is good.

Then i run the new "publish" file to get it to cyberduck.

Everything seems to be good so far, the files are getting transferred over to cyberduck, and its green lights.

But when i then check the website on internet, it just show all the files as an dictonary.

I really appreciate any help!!!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552) Might be a good idea to read [ask] and read the [meta-tag:faq]....